# Is there an xCode equivalent to Unity Prefabs?

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

In unity, I could create an object hierarchy like such:

Canvas
-GameObject
--Sprite
--Button
--Title

and lay them out however I wished, visually, then save it as a prefab. Toss on a script on the parent gameobject, and I could even keep references to the children.

Is there something similar to this in xCode? I know you can make custom controls via code, but that's a pain and a designer can't play with it visually afterwards.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is "no"

Comment: Boo. 
So for example, if I want to make a particular custom button, I need to either make it via code, or set up the outlets manually every time?

Comment: I haven't actually programmed in xcode. You could certainly write your own button class, but in terms of the hierarchical relationship that Unity has? Probably not.